# Html.Raw changes style of the whole page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, stylesheet

I'm rendering HTML page in **ASP.net MVC** with:

```
@(Html.Raw(@Model.Body))
```

for a formatted and styled text contained in Body property of the model, but this changes the CSS style to the whole page.
How can I restrict this only to the div where the Html.Raw is used ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right way to render body. Use this:

```
  @RenderBody()
```

Comment: I need to pass Model.Body to @RenderBody, but this is not allowed as argument.

Comment: Ok. I got it. What is your partial view Model type?

Comment: You need to add a partial view based on that layout and then, add a model to it.

Comment: I've a formatted/styled text in the property 'Body' of my Model. When I try to render in html this text, the Html.Raw include its CSS. This css influences the whole HTML page...

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.Raw` is the one Html helper method to translate the scripting tag in its actual meaning. 
if you write **`< h1 >ASP.NET MVC < /h1 >`** in razor view engine then its simply as it display

but you can write it in `@Html.Raw()` method then it can apply `< H1>` tag
Like **`@Html.Raw("< h1 >ASP.NET MVC < /h1 >")`** then it can display ASP.NET MVC in apply `<H1>` tag style.

So, the when we apply css style or java-script functions in **Razor view engine** then used `@Html.Raw()` method to its actual meaning

Answer (score 0):

delete style tags and content with Regex

```
 @Html.Raw(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Model.HtmlBody, "<style>.*?</style>", string.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline))
```